# Needed Batch command for moving file other than *.bat all others to the different folder

Tags: batch-file

Needed windows Batch command for moving file other than *.bat all others to the different folder.

Comment: Post there your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pushd "c:\folder_with_bat_files"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d^| findstr /i /e /v "bat"') do (
   move /y "%%~fa" "c:\some_dir"
)
```

use `findstr` command to filter the redults of `dir` command.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the update.
yes the code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Also can you send me the Unix command for the same above code....

Comment: @himanshu - better ask a new question.I'm not so experienced with `bash` but `grep` command is pretty similar to `findstr`