# Unix shell command for moving all files other than *.bat to a different folder

Tags: shell, unix

Unix shell command for moving all files other than *.bat to a different folder.

Here in a single folder many file are present and only *.bat files need to be kept rest all need to ne moved to a different folder. It is working fine in window but as i tried to convert this to unix shell command but did not worked.

Something like the below Batch command:

```
pushd "c:\folder_with_bat_files"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d^| findstr /i /e /v "bat"') do (
   move /y "%%~fa" "c:\some_dir"
```

Comment: You seem to be developing a habit of posting poor, low effort "please give me the codez" questions here, like your [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30107337/62576). It was closed for a reason, which is explained right below the post itself in the colored block of text. I'd suggest you read it, and then visit the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages before posting your next question here. We are not a code writing service.

Comment: It's not a particularly good question but it's not a duplicate either, as the other question is about the Windows command prompt, whereas this question is about the POSIX shell.

Comment: Something like `mv *.bat some_dir` might be all you need here. For anything more complex, I would suggest taking a look at the `find` command.

Comment: @TomFenech you are right. I overlooked at it. Reopening. Note what you suggest would move all `*.bat` files, whereas the intended behaviour is the oppositve.

Comment: Rather than giving us some code (someone's answer) to translate for you, it would be better to provide more details about exactly what you're trying to do and in particular, where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi All,
I have already tried may codes but there is a specific condition to move only files other than a specific ones.
yes agree that its like that of my older quesion, but as I cannot keep on changing my question.
Appreciate as its a simple one for you all, as I am beginner.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and show us what you've tried! There are some things which are unclear - does the directory only contain files, or are there directories too? If so, how should the directories be treated? You need to improve your question so that it is easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If your shell supports it and you want to move **everything** that is not a `.bat` file, including directories, I would suggest using extended globs:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
mv path/to/bats/!(*.bat) some_dir
```

`!(*.bat)` expands to all paths except those ending in `.bat`.

If you would like to only move files, then you can use `find`:

```
find path/to/bats -type f ! -name '*.bat' -exec mv '{}' some_dir \;
```

You should be aware that this also moves files found in subdirectories. To avoid this behaviour you can use the `-maxdepth 1` parameter if your version of `find` supports it.

Otherwise, you're stuck with a loop:

```
for f in path/to/bats/*; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        case $f in
            *.bat)
                ;;
            *)
                mv "$f" some_dir
                ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```

Comment: @himanshu I have provided this answer as I think that your question has the potential to be a useful one. I still think that you need to update your question to improve it. Please read the comments below your question and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command:

`ls -ltr | grep -v "bat$" | sed 1d | awk -F ' ' '{print "mv " $9 " /new_dir/"}' |sh`

Run above command without `sh` once to see if move commands are generated correctly.